# Inverting a boolean to create a list of alternate items

Tags: lists

Does anyone know how to invert a boolean in LaTeX? It looks like once you are inside a logical test, resetting the logical value has no effect. Using the etoolbox package, I tried

```
\foreach \n in {1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,e}{
  \iftoggle{pauper}{
    True 
    \togglefalse{pauper}
   }{
    False
    \toggletrue{pauper}
  }
}
```

It should produce True False True False True False True False True False, but produces only a string of ten True. How can I make it come out True False True False ....

If this problem is solved, I can solve a far larger problem. It might be that the larger problem has a more elegant solution I have not though of, so I state it as well:

The context is a textbook, where I write the assignment and the answer together, and then call the assignment file twice. The first time, the boolean value assignment is true, the second time it is false.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ifthenelse{assignment}{$2+2$}{$4$}
...
\end{enumerate}
```

Now, I would like for the answers section to have answers to only the odd numbered problems, except for a teacher's version which would have all. So the \item should ideally be something like this

```
  % if assignment=false, then ...
  % if item counter is odd:
  \item \ifthenelse{assignment}{$2+2$}{$4$}
  % but if item counter is odd:
  \stepcounter{enumi}
  % if assignment=true, then, regardless of counter:
  \item \ifthenelse{assignment}{$2+2$}{$4$}
```

I have tried

```
 \ifthenelse{\boolean{assignment}}{$2+2$}{
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddItem}}{
      \item $4$ \setboolean{oddItem}{false}
     }{
      \stepcounter{enumi} \setboolean{oddItem}{true}
    }
 }
```

But the boolean stays the same value. I have tried several combinations, and also setting it outside the inner ifthenelse like this,

```
\setboolean{oddItem}{\not\boolean{oddItem}}
```

but to no avail. Same with toggle instead of boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the body of `\foreach` is in a group so the effect of local commands is restricted to a single iteration.
What it means for your first example is that `\toggletrue`/`\togglefalse` only have an effect within the same iteration.
To fix this, as suggested in the `etoolbox` manual, you can prefix them with `\global` which extends their effect beyond groups:

```
\foreach \n in {1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,e}{
 \iftoggle{pauper}{
   True 
   \global\togglefalse{pauper}
  }{
   False
   \global\toggletrue{pauper}
 }
}
```

shoud give the desired result.

Without further context, a simpler solution can be provided by using LaTeX `\newif` and `\ifodd` without the need for `etoolbox` and ifthenelse.

First you can create a new conditional with `\newif\ifassignment` and set it to true or false using `\assignmenttrue` `\assignmentfalse`.
Then, if you have a counter (either `\theenumi` or `\n` in your `\foreach`) you can check if it is odd by using `\ifodd`.

```
\begin{itemize}
\foreach\n in {1,...,10}{
  \item Problem \n
  \ifassignment%
    \ifodd\n%
      \relax%
    \else%
      -- Solution \n%
    \fi
  \else%
      -- Solution \n%
  \fi%
}
\end{itemize}
```

The ugly part is that the solution has to be repeated twice.
THere are multiple ways to solve this but the way I am presenting is by introducing a macro `\printproblem` that encapsulates this logics:

```
\newcommand{\printproblem}[2]{
  \item #1%
    \ifassignment%
      \ifodd\n%
        -- #2%
      \else%
        \relax%
      \fi
    \else%
        -- #2%
    \fi%
}
```

An then you can do

```
\begin{itemize}
\foreach\n in {1,...,10}{
 \printproblem{Problem \n}{Solution \n}
}
\end{itemize}
```

If you are not using an actual `\foreach` loop, you can use `\theenumi` instead of `\n`:

```
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{
  \ifassignment%
    \ifodd\theenumi%
      -- #1%
    \else%
      \relax%
    \fi
  \else%
      -- #1%
  \fi%
}
```

and in the body:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Problem 1 \solution{Solution 1}
  \item Problem 2 \solution{Solution 2}
  \item Problem 3 \solution{Solution 3}
  \item Problem 4 \solution{Solution 4}
  \item Problem 5 \solution{Solution 5}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: I am not using the foreach loop, so the latter is more like what I am doing. To be precise, I have defined two boolean variables, that turn on and off the visibility of two environments, oText and oSolution. An assignment looks like this:

    \item Description \oText{$2+2$}\oSolution{$4$}

The file is called twice: first with Text on, Solution off. Then later with Solution on, Text off. I will try to tweak your solution command, so that it's on when Text is, and has \item inside. Then item calls will be like this:

    \solution{ \item Description \oText{$2+2$}\oSolution{$4$} }

Look OK?

Comment: If you make progress but find other problems you can always post a new question. I believe the first part of my answer addresses your question quite directly. If this answered your question please consider marking it as an accepted answer.